# French accents are not accepting in eclipse Galileo,so how fix this?-android

Tags: android, eclipse, internationalization

I want to make the text in French in my app.so i converted English to French but its not accepted in my app.so how to fix this error.

Comment: I don't use Eclipse but my guess would be it's a character-set setting somewhere.

Comment: How does one say "android" in a french accent, anyway?

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the encoding for your files ? Use UTF-8:

> File properties > Resource > Text file
>   encoding

Answer (score 0):

> Preferences->General->workspace->text file encoding: select ISO-8859-1.